# Read remote html body

Tags: javascript, html

I feel dumb asking this, but I tried everything and nothing works... So here it go:
I'm doing a BHO to deny some prohibited sites. So when I find some target URL, I just cancel navigation and call a procedure to read another body. And this procedure is the problem. I tried via iframe like this:

```
iFrame:= Document.createElement('iframe');
iFrame.setAttribute('src', 'denied.html', 0);
iFrame.setAttribute('position', 'absolute', 0);
iFrame.style.width:= '100%';
iFrame.style.height:= '100%';
iFrame.style.left:= '0px';
iFrame.style.top:= '0px';
iFrame.style.border:= '0px';
(Document.body as IHTMLDomNode).appendChild(iFrame as IHTMLDomNode);
```

but didn't worked. the iframe don't overlap the entire website, just a part of it. so i tried with this:

```
Document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<body onload="document.location=denied.html">');
```

but nothing too... and tried many other html codes to this, but nothing worked. how can I read another remote page on this way? remembering that i'm using ihtmldocument2,ihtmlelement... and i'm newbie in this subject. waiting for answers! thanks brothers.

Comment: So the browser can still download the page, you just want to overlay (cover up) the site? Why not just force the window/tab to redirect to a local error file? *Before* downloading the page?

Comment: Download or not the page is not the main problem. I can cancel the navigation on event BeforeNavigate2. But I'll still need to redirect people to some remote denied.html page... instead of showing the website that he was going to.

Comment: Exactly. I'm not that familiar with BHOs, but `window.location = '\your\path\to\denied.html';` might work. You might have to find the method which allows you to do so, maybe cancel the navigate and call your own?